# Generate access token from postman to access open epic sanbox app to perfom api calls

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, hl7-fhir

I am new to [open epic fhir.](https://fhir.epic.com/) My intentation is to create a [sandbox app](https://fhir.epic.com/Developer/Apps), use that app from [postman](https://www.postman.com/) to simply query using [patient read](https://fhir.epic.com/Sandbox?api=931) api call.

I have created an app. Where I have these fields:

- Client ID
- Non-Production Client ID
- Redirect URI (I have set it to : fhir.epic.com)
- Sandbox Client Secret
- SMART on FHIR Version -> R4
- FHIR ID Generation Scheme  ->Use Unconstrained FHIR IDs (Not sure which should be it)

Now, I in the postman, I would like to generate access token so that I can query using the api.
The type of authentication I have set is: OAuth2.0. See the attached image for the params.
The client Id I used is, non-production client Id provided in the app. There is also only "client id" .

[image]

Using these params, when I try to generate access token, I get **"Error: invalid_client"**
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You aren't following the correct workflow for requesting an access token. Have you reviewed the steps at https://fhir.epic.com/Documentation?docId=oauth2? Since you are using Postman, it seems you are trying to connect through back-end authentication, so you should follow the steps at https://fhir.epic.com/Documentation?docId=oauth2&section=BackendOAuth2Guide. You would be passing a signed JWT, not a client ID and secret.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment. 
I have already gone through the link before posting the question. As I am not sure what is the correct workflow, I have posted here. If you know how to connect from postman and what kind of app (backend or normal ) that should be, please share.

Comment: The type of app is up to you and will be based on your expectations for who (if anyone) will interact with your app and how. If your app will be used by a patient or clinician, then it will be a SMART on FHIR app or a standalone app. If there is no user interaction and you are integrating server-to-server, then it would be a back-end app. Authenticating through Postman would be most appropriate for a back-end app.

The steps are in the documentation; the starting point for back-end OAuth is to create a public-private key pair and to build a signed JWT, so make sure you've done that.

Comment: As I said I have read the documentations. Mine is a standalone sanbox dummy app. 

All I am trying to figure out how to generate access token from postman app to query using open epic fhir api. As a non-web developer , I am having hard time configuring these stuff just reading the documentation. 

However, assuming you are correct, Do you have an example where I  can see that how the fields exists in backened app can be used to configure in postman. 
For example, what should be the redirect url. Shall I use non-production client id, or only client id.  In the building apps

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was struggling with the same issue for the past 2 days. I finally succeded and since it's fresh in my mind I will reconstruct the steps needed to obtain the access token for the EPIC Sandbox environment:

NOTE: this applies to Windows environment

1. Open the PowerShell as an Administrator
2. Execute the following command:  New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "MyTestApp"
3. Open the Microsoft Management Console (MMC.EXE) and load Certificates snap-in for your Machine (Computer)
4. Expand the Personal->Certificates node in MMC snap-in
5. You are supposed to see the self-signed certificate that you created in step 2
6. Right-click on that certificate and select "All tasks" -> "Export"
7. Click "Next" then select "Yes, export the private key" then "Next"
8. Leave the defaults although not sure should the "Enable certificate privacy" option stay selected (if doesn't work retry the
   operation from this step by removing that option)
9. Choose you password and export the certificate to a .pfx file
10. Install the OpenSSL ([Open SSL for Windows](https://slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL_Light-3_2_0.msi))
11. Open Command Prompt as an Administrator, navigate to OpenSSL\bin folder instalation and execute the following command: openssl.exe pkey -in "[the path and the .pfx file] from step 9" -out "[the path and the name of .pem file you are exporting private key]" -traditional
12. You will be asked for password from point 9. This "-traditional" parameter from a point 11 is what basically costed me 2 days of work and I discovered it by pure accident
13. The file you created contains the private key. You will need the contents of that file but stripped of newline (the whole content in one continuous line)
14. Finally, you have an example Postman library togehter with environment on this address: [EPIC Open Postman library](https://www.postman.com/interstellar-capsule-675441/workspace/emr-connect-epic-cerner-etc/collection/8220383-9484e4b1-8299-4dc2-adf5-c4befdfb96eb). Adapt the ClientID ("Non-Production Client ID" in your Epic enviroment) and the Epic_IntegrationLab_PrivateKey with the content of file from the point 12 (don't forget to strip the newline)